# Java NIO File Channel writing to file

Tags: java, io, nio

I am sending file over internet and the receiver receives the position of the file it was sent from and of course the data, I am supposed to write the data received on the file starting from the position sent but it looks like NIO likes to over write any data before the position.

So what I am doing is

```
fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(file)).getChannel();
```

then i write on it the buffer starting from pos thats defined before

```
fc.write(buffer, pos);
```

When i send file that is splitted for more than one piece and writing the data to file like I showed for some reason the data written before gets overwritten by zeros

I've also tried debugging in such ways as checking that its actually starting to write from the position and it worked correctly and having a delay between transfers so they couldn't write on the file concurrent which shouldn't be problem anyway.

I am also closing the channel

```
fc.close();
```

because I am sending the file in pieces I can't keep the fc in memory.

Whats wrong with my code or how can I possibly write in file starting from x position without emptying the data before the position?

Comment: `fc.write(buffer, pos);` writes bytes to file from beginning, but from `pos` position in buffer. are you sure that you continuing writing to file? Or you rewriting all bytes to begining of the file?

Comment: "I am sending the file in pieces I can't keep the fc in memory." That doesn't make any sense to me. Have you tired `RandomAccessFile` instead?

Comment: Alaster, fc.write takes position of file as parameter, and I am sure pos is set right as I said.

Peter
Well I can but its easier to open it each time packet is reiceved IF ITS POSSIBLE as I don't think thats heavy operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way to copy between channels is as follows:

```
while (in.read(buffer) > 0 || buffer.hasRemaining())
{
  buffer.flip();
  out.write(buffer);
  buffer.compact();
}
```

If you're closing and reopening the file you will need to open it in append mode after the first time.